# sql dynamic limit based on first occurence

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming the following table:

```
user, timestamp, status_code
1, 2017-08-21 09:03:50, 404
2, 2017-08-21 09:03:48, 200
1, 2017-08-21 09:03:45, 404
1, 2017-08-21 09:03:42, 404
1, 2017-08-21 09:03:41, 200
1, 2017-08-21 09:03:40, 404
```

How can I select all entries from a user that are 404 LIMITed by the first occurence of a 200 for that user:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE user = 1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC ... ???
```

expected result:

```
user, timestamp, status_code
1, 2017-08-21 09:03:50, 404
1, 2017-08-21 09:03:45, 404
1, 2017-08-21 09:03:42, 404
```

Comment: can you explain the logic in detail? it is unclear  from the expected result.

Comment: Also, which RDBMS are you using. MySQL, Sql Server, Postgres, etc..?

Comment: Why wouldn't you also include the first record. It's for the same user and occurs after the 200 for that user.

Comment: @JNevill I am using MySQL

Comment: @JNevill yes, should also be included. was a copy paste error

Comment: Get the timestamp of the first 200 as a subquery, then get all the 404 rows whose timestamp is older than it

Answer (score 2):

You can use a correlated sub query to get this.

```
select * from tbl t1
where timestamp > (select t2.timestamp 
                   from tbl t2 
                   where t1.user_id=t2.user_id and t2.status_code=200
                   order by t2.timestamp
                   limit 1)
and status_code=404
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT tbl.* FROM tbl, 
    (SELECT user, MIN(timestamp) AS min_ts 
     FROM tbl 
     WHERE status_code = 200 
     GROUP BY user
    ) AS subtable
WHERE status_code = 404 
AND tbl.user = subtable.user 
AND tbl.timestamp > subtable.min_ts
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf725/3

Comment: THis does not get the condition to get all the rows before the 200 row

Comment: Edited the answer (sorry if that's the wrong approach) - as pointed out, I didn't originally answer the question re: the timestamp filter.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your query to be looking for all rows with status 404 and a timestamp earlier than any row with status 200 for the same user.

I'd think of this by reversing the logic: *try* to join each 404 row to an earlier row for the same user with status 200, and if none is found, then the 404 row is one you want to select. When no such row is found, the outer join will make all the columns of the joined row NULL.

```
select t1.*
from tbl as t1
left outer join tbl as t2
  on t2.status_code = 200
  and t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
  and t1.timestamp > t2.timestamp 
where t1.status_code = 404 
  and t2.user_id is NULL -- i.e. when the outer join finds no match
```

An index on columns (status_code, user_id, timestamp) in that order will help optimize both the WHERE condition for t1 and the JOIN condition for t2.

Logically, my answer is similar to the answer from Vamsi Prabhala, but mine uses a join instead of a correlated subquery, so mine should be easier to optimize.